# Custom TFT Screen Question

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, display, tft

I'm looking to get a custom Resistive Touch TFT screen made for a project. The company have specified that the screen will utilize a F31L-1A7H1-11040 type connection to go between the screen and microcontroller I want to use.

My question is - does the screen manufacturer need to specify a display controller for me to use for this project (E.g IL9341 Chip) - or is this something I can select myself. I've added the pinout for the screen below in case it helps. [image: Screen Pinout]

Comment: Ask them what they recommend for their tech.

Comment: @Andyaka more so I am confused, with this pinout I could use any controller that I find that suits - or only one specific controller can be used for this screen that they recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a TFT screen, the control chip is embedded into the screen, so they have to specify it, and you need to make sure you can drive it.

Besides, the control chip like ILI9341 have several method of drive, SPI, SPI with additional line, 8 bit parallel, 16bit parallel, and this is chosen from some pin setup of the chip. (Yours seems to be SPI)

Not all TFT display has an actual pin to select the mode, some are directly set within the flex ribbon, so you need to make sure you have the control logic you want or that the pin to set it are available.

Besides all that, TFT can be quite tricky to get started and some libraries are really messy. Stay away from Microchip stack.

Make sure to get the driver for the particular chip and particular logic for your MCU, some control chip are quite obscure and drivers a tricky to write because you have no feedback until the screen start to display something.

I had good success with STM32 and their stack, ST have an awesome UI designer, [TouchGFX](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/ecosystems/stm32-graphic-user-interface.html) and a solid display stack which is definitely what I would recommend. Took me a while to check different solution and I think that is the best.

Make sure your chip has a fast SPI and clock to have good refresh rate.

[Here](https://helentronica.com/2021/01/22/touchgfx-on-a-custom-made-low-cost-board-with-the-ili9341-controller-over-spi/) is a driver for the TouchGFX stack an ILI9341 if that is the chip you have, I used it and works well.

EDIT:
Get started with TouchGFX:

It's a bit daumpting at first because you need to use STM32CubeIDE, STM32CubeMX and TouchGFX all together.

Create your project on the IDE and use the MX to configure and generate code (download and activate the GFX libs), then you can open from the IDE the GFX software to make your screens.

TouchGFX has some driver for some chips, but not all, you can find quite a bunch on the internet and implement it in the GFX stack.

If you want to avoid headache, choose a controller that has a driver on the stack already implemented or that has some good *how to* online.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, the company had mentioned to me before that they could help me integrate their controller onto my custom microcontroller board rather than on board their screen. Could this be the case or may I have misunderstood the meaning of this?

Comment: Maybe they were referring to the touch controller, usually the TFT driver chip is within the display and seems to be the case on the pinout. However based on the pinout, you need an external touch controller or perhaps the driver stack. @BrandonKellett

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I use an STM32 controller, would I be able to use TouchGFX (it seems quite powerful/useful) irrespective of the control chip used on the screen? Or this would be totally dependent on what the company specify?

Comment: @BrandonKellett I edited my question with clarification for touchGFX

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, this exactly the info I was searching for!